# (python) Can you please tell me what is the problem in the code below

Tags: python, list, indexing

I just start to learn python and i have a problem:

```
arr = [1,3,3,3,0,1,1]
def solution(arr):  
    a=[]
    for r in range(len(arr)-1):
        if arr[r] == arr[r+1]:
            a.append(r+1)
    print(a)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        k = int(a[i])
        arr[k] = -1
        arr.remove(-1)
    return arr
```

There's a message

```
IndexError: list index out of range for ''arr[k] = -1''
```

Can you please tell me the reason for the Error and correct it?

Comment: Print the values of arr and k in that loop, and it will be clear.

Comment: can you please tell what you want to do here? what are you expecting as output? what does your code intend to do?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: I suppose to remove the successive same number, so I want the code to return [1,3,0,1]

Comment: It should be [1,3,3,0,1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it results in a Runtime exception. The list `a` stores indices. For each element `v` in `a`, you are trying to remove the value `arr[v]`. Doing this will reduce the size of `arr` by one every time. So, in the next iteration, `v` can be greater than the size of `arr`. Hence, it results in List index out of bound exception.

Your code, corrected:

```
arr = [1,3,3,3,0,1,1]
def solution(arr):  
    a=[]
    for r in range(len(arr)-1):
        if arr[r] == arr[r+1]:
            a.append(r+1)
    print(a)
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        k = int(a[i])
        arr[k - c] = -1
        arr.remove(-1)
        c += 1
    return arr
    
print(solution(arr))
```

It looks like you are trying to remove consecutive duplicates from the list. This can be easily solved using the following code.

```
def remove_duplicates(arr):
    stack = [arr[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if stack[-1] != arr[i]:
            stack.append(arr[i])
    return stack

print(remove_duplicates([1,3,3,3,0,1,1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot modify the array shape when you have determined the indices based on the unmodified array to index into it.

Here is something that you might be looking for:

```
def solution(arr):
    a = []
    for r in range(len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[r] == arr[r + 1]:
            a.append(r + 1)
    print(a)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        k = int(a[i])
        arr[k] = -1

        # In the following line, you cannot modify the array length
        # when you have already computed the indices based on the unmodified array
        # arr.remove(-1)
    arr = [x for x in arr if x != -1]  # This is a better way to deal with it
    return arr


print(solution(arr=[1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t want to mess with the original list. Otherwise you’ll run into index errors. Index errors mean the item you were looking for in the list no longer exists. Most likely this line was the culprit `arr.remove(-1)`.

```py
arr = [1,3,3,3,0,1,1]

solution = []
for i, v in enumerate(arr):
    if i == 0 or v != arr[i -1]:
        solution.append(v)
    
print(solution)
```

This should get you what you are after. `enumerate` tells you want index you are at when looping through the list. More information can be found here: https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've probably already know what wrong happened here, removing the element inside the `loop`:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    k = int(a[i])
    arr[k] = -1
    arr.remove(-1)
```

You can fix the whole thing just changing the line to this list filter+lambda implementation, well, not inside the loop, but after the completion of loop iterations, just like follows:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    k = int(a[i])
    arr[k] = -1
arr = list(filter(lambda x: x != -1, arr))
```

And you'll get what you want just from your solution!